# makeStyles classes doesn't overwrite the main components classes

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm using makeStyles from Material-UI in ReactJS to style components but classes are injected first in header and doesn't overwrite the component classes.

This is the head styles screenshot:
[image: a busy cat]

As you can see, makeStyles did the "OAuth" classes, but are being injected first and not later making impossible to overwrite the components classes.

this is my style (makeStyles) code:

```
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/styles';

const useStyles = makeStyles(
  theme => ({
    container: {
      alignItems: 'start',
      [theme.breakpoints.down('xs')]: {
        display: 'block',
        margin: 0,
        padding: 0
      }
    },
    paper: {
      width: '100%',
      maxWidth: '600px',
      margin: '.5rem',
      marginTop: '15vh',
      [theme.breakpoints.down('xs')]: {
        margin: 0,
        height: '100%',
        maxHeight: '100%'
      }
    }
  }),
  { name: 'OAuth' }
);

export default useStyles;
```

And this is how I'm trying to overwrite classes:

```
import React from 'react';
import useStyles from './styles';
import Dialog from '@material-ui/core/Dialog';
import Box from '@material-ui/core/Box';

const OAuth = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const oauthClasses = {
    container: classes.container,
    paper: classes.paper
  };

  return (
    <Dialog open={true} classes={oauthClasses}>
      <Box>
        Dialog content
      </Box>
    </Dialog>
  );
};

export default OAuth;
```

So, how could I make my classes to be injected at the end to overwrite the main classes of the components?

Comment: The issue is with the order of your imports. Import the `useStyles` function after importing all of the Material-UI components. See my other answer (in the "duplicate" flag comment) for more details.